# How to improve the performance of query in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in MongoDB with more than 5 million documents. Whenever I create a document inside the same collection I have to check if there exists any document with same title and if it exists then I don't have to add this to the database.

Example: here is my MongoDB document:

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("3a434sa3242424sdsdw"),
"title":"Lost in space",
"desc":"this is description"
}
```

Now whenever a new document is being created in the collection, I want to check if the same **title** already exists in any of the documents and if it does not exists, then only I want to add it to the database.

Currently, I am using *findOne* query and checking for the title, if it not available only then it is added to the database. I am facing the performance issue in this. It is taking too much time to do this process. Please suggest a better approach.

```
async function addToDB(data){
let result= await db.collection('testCol').findOne({title:data.title});
if(result==null){
   await db.collection('testCol').insertOne(data);
 }else{
   console.log("already exists in db");
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `index` on title? You just want to insert/ update also for same key?

Comment: I have an `index` on the title. And I want to create a new document if the same title is not present in any of the documents.

Comment: I will implement this and will get back to you

Comment: Add a unique index on title.

Comment: @D.SM since I have more than 5 million unique it's not possible to add a unique index to `title`. And these records will increase with time.

Comment: 5 million unique what and why do you think this affects your ability to create the index?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the `network round trip time` which is currently 2X. Because you execute two queries. One for find then one for update. You can combine them into one query as below.

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   { $setOnInsert: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

It will not update if already exists.

```
db.test.update(
   {"key1":"1"},
   { $setOnInsert: { "key":"2"} },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

It looks for document with `key1` is 1. If it finds, it skips. If not, it inserts using the data provided in the object of `setOnInsert`.

Comment: yeah sure, I am evaluating the answer, if you found the question useful you can upvote it too.

Comment: Sure, Let me know once you evaluated. @AdityaJoshi

Comment: it's working as of now. But didn't got the performance metric.